# compile android app in eclipse ignoring java error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile an app for a custom rom where `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FLOATING_WINDOW);` can be used. But compiling it in android seems to cause errors and stop me from doing it. Is there a way i can disable error check on a specific .java file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no (public) `Intent.FLAG_FLOATING_WINDOW` constant, according to the sdk documentation, hence the compile error. Presumably, it's specific to the custom rom your attempting to build for?

You cannot just bypass a compile error like this. However, since we're talking about a constant, you may be able to substitute the reference with the actual value. All the flag constants defined by the `Intent` class are simply `int`s, but you'd have to know the value in order to be able to replace it. You should be able to find that somewhere in the custom rom's source that you're referring to.

For example, suppose the contant would have the following definition:

```
public static final int FLAG_FLOATING_WINDOW = 1234;
```

Then a valid `addFlags()` call using this value would look like this:

```
addFlags(1234);
```

That will build, irrespective of the constant definitions in `Intent`.

---

**Edit:**

The question was related to Paranoid Android, for which the FLAG_FLOATING_WINDOW declaration is as follows.

```
/**
 * If set, this intent will always match start up as a floating window
 * in mutil window scenarios.
 */
public static final int FLAG_FLOATING_WINDOW = 0x00002000;
```

Source: [Intent.java (@ParanoidAndroid)](https://github.com/ParanoidAndroid/android_frameworks_base/blob/jellybean/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#L3323)

Comment: sounds like it could work. so for normal flags, is the int values stored in android.jar or somewhere else like the frame work.

Comment: @LukePring: all the constant declarations can be found in the source of `Intent.java`. I had a quick look in the SlimRoms repo (it seems like that's the custom rom you're referring to?), but can't seem to find the `FLAG_FLOATING_WINDOW` anywhere in [the included `Intent` class](https://github.com/SlimRoms/frameworks_base/blob/jb4.2/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#L3094) (in any of the branches).

Comment: nope, paranoid android. and i just found the int. Thanks guys :)